# Light in Paraview

Tags: light, paraview

As I try to draw the earth, I want so use the light as the sun to simulate day and night.

Is there any way to change the light position?

Right now it is set as a headlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ParaView 5.5.2, You can add any kind of lights using `View->Light Inspector`.